# structure calloc c

Tags: c, struct, calloc

C99 gcc

I keep getting this error. I have a struct outside main. And inside main I am trying to allocate on the stack using calloc. I can't seem to find out what is wrong.

Thanks for any advice,

error: expected expression before ‘)’ token

```
/* global */
struct port_data_t                                                                      
{                                                                                       
    size_t task_id;                                                                     
    pthread_t *thread_id;                                                               
    size_t start_port;                                                                  
    size_t number_ports;                                                                
} *port_data;                                                                           


/* main function */
struct port_data_t *port_data = (struct task_data_t*) calloc(4, sizeof(port_data*));
```

Comment: any reason you are casting to a different type than the one you are assigning to?

Comment: I made some changes. Should be this:
struct port_data_t *port_data = (struct port_data_t*) calloc(4, sizeof(port_data*));

Comment: I think you might need to post the entire code (if not too long)

Comment: calloc() allocates memory on heap rather then on stack so you have to manually free() it to prevent leaks. alloca() allocates on stack but it is not standard fucntion - neither C99 nor POSIX. However it is present in BSD and Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should be `calloc(4, sizeof(*port_data))`: Note * *befor*e var name.

Answer (score 4):

should be sizeof(port_data_t) not sizeof(port_data*). The former is the size of a port_data_t struct. The latter doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I prefer using *<allocated ptr>, less breakage if the type changes.

Comment: Should be sizeof(struct port_data_t), not sizeof(port_data_t) unless I'm badly mistaken.

Comment: A pluser! Kill the heathen pluser! :)

Comment: I think this is the best answer 'cause the one accepted could create misunderstanding between `*<allocated ptr>` and `<allocated ptr>*`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
struct port_data_t *port_data = (struct task_data_t*) calloc(4, sizeof(port_data*));
```

To this:

```
port_data = (struct port_data_t*) calloc(4, sizeof(*port_data));
```

Might work a little better. If you've declaring `port_data` as a global struct, you don't need to re-declare it as a `struct port_data_t`. GCC should already know that. Of course, how I would do it is this:

```
port_data = (struct port_data_t*) calloc(4, sizeof(struct port_data_t));
```

But I don't like putting variables in `sizeof()`. I try to stick with putting types in there, just out of habit. Plus, it resolves any ambiguities about how exactly a pointer needs to be dereferenced, which is tripping you up in this case.

Comment: Of course, using the variable is much safer when you are changing the pointer type...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct port_data_t {
    size_t task_id;
    pthread_t *thread_id;
    size_t start_port;
    size_t number_ports;
} port_data_t;

port_data_t* f() {
    port_data_t* ports = (port_data_t*)calloc(4, sizeof(port_data_t));
    return ports;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jeffamaphone, task_data_t is out of context. And also pointed out by Crashworks, try sizeof (port_data_t) if you want an array of structures into port_data.

Using sizeof (port_data*) will make it allocate sizeof pointer to pointer of port_data_t which in most cases is only so useful in most of the cases.

Comment: No, he means sizeof(struct port_data_t). I've checked this with GCC and it doesn't work without the struct keyword in there.